# Add a Keyboard shortcut to AutoKeys macro from VBA in Access 2003

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2003

I have an Access 2003 application and it has AutoKeys macro. I would like to add an another Keyboard shortcut to this application from my VBA module. How can I do that?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You want to edit the macro from code? Why? Seems like a terrible idea to me.

Comment: I need to add the Keyboard ShortCut from my custom module on over 60 computers on Legacy System. I just don't want to add the keyboard shortcut manually on each computer.

Comment: I still don't get it. When you update the front end, you just distribute a new one to the users, copying over top of the old one. Of course, this assumes you have a distribution mechanism in place and that you've not made the rookie mistake of distributing and unsplit application.

Comment: Wow, Thanks. Why I didn't think of it. Put it in answer please, I'll select as this as solution. I will use saveastext and loadfromtext.

Comment: That's not what I suggested. You're still thinking in terms of updating the objects in a front end, whereas you should just REPLACE it with the new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To alter your front end, just edit it the way you want it and then distribute the updated front end to your users. Don't muck about with altering an existing front end, as front ends are completely disposable -- just replace it with the updated one.